# How do you shift the descender line?

Tags: css, typography

I'm trying to figure out how to shift the descender line for a block of text, to move all of the descenders in letters such as "y" and "g" to show up above the baseline, but not actually shift the baseline. Is there any way to do this without using a special font?

Comment: You could try using the <sup> tag, but that makes the font smaller also.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no typographic adept, but I don't think you can control the baseline, the descender line and the positions of letters with descenders using CSS alone.

If some font formats (and some fonts) support such a thing, there may be a chance that the upcoming [`font-feature-settings` property](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-fonts/#font-feature-settings-prop) may allow adjusting that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no typography expert either, as @BoltClock suggests, this is probably not possible in any generic way except eventually through `font-feature-settings`. CSS doesn't offer this fine a level of typographic control.

The only (terrible) workaround that comes to my mind is shifting each character individually using `position: relative` - it may be acceptable for a heading, but probably isn't in any other context.

If I understand you correctly, it would have to look like this:

```
 span { font-size: 40px  }
 span.g  { position: relative; top: -6px; }
 span.y  { position: relative; top: -4px; }

 <span>Lorem <span class="y">y</span>psum Dolor Sit 
 <span class="g">g</span>amet</span>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eqfsZ/4/)

It would even be possible to cook up some jQuery to do this automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use `vertical-align` style with a percentage value and a inline wrapper around those specific characters, in order to raise them relative to the others. I think this would be the best kludge. Its a little more semantic then using a relative height. You could try `super` too I suppose, if you don't have funky, irregular descenders.